# How to import a custom file into APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin

As we know apk file is a zip formatted archive file including following files and folders:

- AndroidManifest.xml
- assets
- classes.dex
- META-INF
- res
- resources.arsc

What I want is to include a custom file (ie: `README.txt`) in `apk` just sitting near files above. This file should also be included in `Generated Signed APK` (which means README.txt should be signed too). I am using Android Studio, and the process should be automated while compiling (or releasing, or even a simple script would be nice). I have tried to add some dummy

```
dependencies {  
    include file.....
```

but no luck. How do you turn this on? `:P`

---

How to include an arbitrary custom file in APK while building the project so that `Generate Signed APK`should also sign the arbitrary file while signing the rest, in Android Studio?

Comment: Why don't you include that file into your `assets` or into your `res/raw` folder? It would be so dumb-easy to manage it...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein the file is not meant to be used by android itself.

Comment: So, why do you want to include it? I don't get the use of it.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein think this is a kind of signature(not a cryptographic one) or ID should be included in archive files and in the system all archive files are not meant to be an android app, sometimes it is just a zip file. so it would be also dumb to have an `assets` folder in each archive.

Comment: I'm really not getting what you're trying to do. I'm sure there's an easy solution (sometimes it's under our nose and we just don't see it - I can see the tip of my nose, if I cross my eyes, but I can't see my mouth!), and willing to help. But I'm not getting the problem.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein the problem is to have a custom file in the apk. I can do it by uzing WinZip over the apk file but this breaks the `Generate Signed APK` automated chain. I had to sign myself externally. I am wondering if there is an easy way in Android Studio.

Comment: Is it **your** app? Or are you trying to add something to an existing app? because this can be really tricky...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I develop the android app so the APK file on Android Studio. However the requirement comes from a system that I don't touch.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of guesses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to tell the source set to include the files.  For example if your file is `MyApp/src/main/resources/README.txt` then you can include that file in your output apk by specifying it in the `sourceSet` as one of the `resources`.  For jars you can use this to include `META-INF` info also.

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.includes = [ '**/README.txt' ]
        }
    }
}
```

The same works for `aar`, `apk`, `jar` and probably others (for jars your source set obviously isn't under the `android` closure)