# Add a custom file into android AAR during compilation using build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android library project which builds an AAR file. The structure of my AAR file is

- jni
- classes.jar
- AndroidManifest.xml
- res
- META-INF
- R.txt

Now I want somehow inside the module level build.gradle file add a file into the producing AAR in the same level as the files mentioned above (the highest level). I saw [a similar question for APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172325/how-to-import-a-custom-file-into-apk) tried that solution, but it adds the file inside the "classes.jar", not next to it. A tool `aapt` can do what I want, but it need it to be done inside gradle file during compilation. Can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code snippet to your android library's `build.gradle.kts`(you can interpret to groovy, should be similar). It uses the new Variant API (`androidComponents` `onVariants`).

The `BundlAar` is a `Zip` Type Task, you can refer [Zip Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html) to configure extra files(`from(...)`) or perform any other actions.

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant->
        afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.named("bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}Aar").configure {
                val t = this as com.android.build.gradle.tasks.BundleAar
                t.from(file("test-file.txt"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: running successfully with a test file]

Comment: I was happy to find this, but this seems not to be possible in a App module? Gradle says that bundle[..]Aar is not present, and I checked all tasks and it's not there indeed.

Comment: @Peterdk The question is about AAR or the "Library" build process. You are trying it in the Application module which does not work since APK package task is not a Zip type. Refer to `com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication` for more information.

Comment: I get a "Could not find method onVariants()" when trying to translate to Groovy